# awk condition is not working properly

Tags: command-line, text-processing, awk

These are the data on which I am applying an `awk` command:

```
~$ cat lab4.data
Mike Harrington: (510) 548-1278:250:100:175
Christian Dobbins: (408) 538-2358:155:90:201
Susan Dalsass: (206) 654-6279:250:60:50
Archie McNichol: (206) 548-1348:250:100:175
Jody Savage: (206) 548-1278:15:188:150
Guy Quigley: (916) 343-6410:250:100:175
Dan Savage: (406) 298-7744:450:300:275
Nancy McNeil: (206) 548-1278:250:80:75
John Goldenrod: (916) 348-4278:250:100:175
Chet Main: (510) 548-5258:50:95:135
Tom Savage: (408) 926-3456:250:168:200
Elizabeth Stachelin: (916) 440-1763:175:75:300
```

I need to find the rows with a last value less than `75`. but the condition `$5<75` is not working. Here is an example of the `awk` command I'm using:

```
awk -F: '$5 < 50 {print $0}' lab4.data
```

Here is the output I am getting by the above command:

```
~$ awk -F: '$5 < 50 {print $0}' lab4.data 
Mike Harrington: (510) 548-1278:250:100:175
Christian Dobbins: (408) 538-2358:155:90:201
Archie McNichol: (206) 548-1348:250:100:175
Jody Savage: (206) 548-1278:15:188:150
Guy Quigley: (916) 343-6410:250:100:175
Dan Savage: (406) 298-7744:450:300:275
John Goldenrod: (916) 348-4278:250:100:175
Chet Main: (510) 548-5258:50:95:135
Tom Savage: (408) 926-3456:250:168:200
Elizabeth Stachelin: (916) 440-1763:175:75:300
```

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Copy the text here and use code formatting instead.

Comment: The output of `cat -A lab4.data` or `cat lab4.data | od -tx1` would be more useful that plain `cat lab4.data` - it's possible that there is some trailing non-printing character that is causing `$5` to be converted as a string (which would force lexical rather than numeric comparison)

Comment: Unfortunately the latest edit seems to have lost the information that the lines in the output are all those that are *lexically* less than `50`

Answer (score 2):

You have to use the following awk script

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=":"}{if($5<75) print $0;}' lab4.data
```

[image]

- It was very tedious to type your input data. Next time, please consider pasting terminal output as text

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of terminal output.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. But I have already answered the question that too with the proper formatting of text.

Answer (score 0):

Probably your input file lab4.data was created in Windows and has CRLF line endings.

If the output of

```
awk -F: '{print $NF}' lab4.data | hexdump -c
```

has "\r  \n" in it and instead of "\n" for line break, this is the case. Then you could convert the file to UNIX format, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2613800/4414935), and use the converted file as input for AWK.